# Trouble passing datetime parameter to web service, in GET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I created a web service using ASP .NET Web API. The method is:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("service/{applicantUser}/{lastUpdate:datetime?}")]
    public IHttpActionResult getService(String applicantUser, DateTime? lastUpdate = null){
    // some stuff here

 }
```

If I call the WS in this way:

```
http://myserver/api/service/myusername/2008-12-10
```

all works good, and I obtain a correct json file. But if I try to add the time:

```
http://myserver/api/service/myusername/2008-12-10T12:30:00
```

I obtain the error `404 - Bad Request`

Comment: Does this URL work: `http://myserver/api/service/myusername/?lastUpdate=2008-12-10T12:30:00`

Comment: Oh, yes, It works. But, is there any way for avoid RPC style?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the colon (`:`) character in the URL which is not allowed. You can either put the parameter in the query string:

```
http://myserver/api/service/myusername/?lastUpdate=2008-12-10T12:30:00
```

Or disable the validation to check for potentially dangerous request paths by merging this to your `web.config`:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <pages validateRequest="false" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Ok, thank you! Do you think it is really dangerous disable the validation?

Comment: Well I suppose it's there for a very good reason. But, better to make up your own mind and read the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: why do not use encoding for doing that stuff?

Comment: @anatol Because that doesn't answer the question being asked.

Comment: @DavidG didn't get why not

Comment: @anatol The question is about why the colon is causing problems, this answer tells you how to fix that. Whether you should pass the values encoded or not is a different question.

Comment: @DavidG I can't find any word about 'colon'. Anyway, could you answer - may it be kind of solution or not? I mean url encoding

Comment: @anatol Of course it's a solution, but if you have a question, please ask one rather than commenting on other answers.

Comment: @DavidG I found your answer helpful, but still wonder why not encoding ) it is actual because encoding doesn't work for me, I'm getting 404

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the colon (:) character is causing your bad request error as it is an active character within the url schema.

You'll have to find a way to deserialize or accept it as a parameter without the colon character, or alternately you can try and parse your date from an anchor (#) as a url can be parsed safely with a colon within an anchor. eg: `http://myserver/api/service/myusername#2008-12-10T12:30:00`

Comment: this *should* be parsable using `Route("service/{applicantUser}#{lastUpdate:datetime?}")`

Comment: Really? Pretty sure anything after the `#` will not be passed to the server.

Comment: You're right! My mistake - Fortunately it seems you can also have a colon within a querystring which *will* be sent to the server, so that would be: `http://myserver/api/service/myusername?t=2008-12-10T12:30:00`

Answer (score 0):

As my predecessors have already mentioned correctly, the ":" character causes the error.

One way to circumvent this is to use URL-encoded parameters. So when you try to set the lastUpdate parameter by hand:
Use "%3A" instead of the ":" (colon), which is the URL-encoded representation of the colon character.

In case you're constructing the Route from within an application:
`HttpUtility.UrlEncode()`
is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to disable security settings, you can send DateTime as string, without potentially dangerous symbols. Send string like this:

```
String date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyyTHH-mm-s");
```

And then, parse it on controller side with your special pattern:

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateToParse, "MM-dd-yyyyTHH-mm-s", new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime date)) {
// your code here   
}
```

Comment: MM-dd-yyyyTHH-mm-s doesn't work, but thanks for trying :)